# IOS 8 VPN framework

Tags: ios, ios8, vpn

I have created a VPN profile programmatically using NetworkExtension APIs.

I have two questions here:

1. [_vpnManager setOnDemandRules: array]; what should be the content of the array?
2. While I am calling saveToPreferencesWithCompletionHandler, I am getting a install profile dialog pop up. Is there a way to suppress the pop up?

Answer (score 0):

To answer question 1: I'd say an array of `NEOnDemandRule` objects (see `NEOnDemandRule.h`).

Comment: Yes, I got it working by an array of NEOnDemandRule objects. Do you have any info about 2?